# Ideal Global/Local Work Group Sizes (OpenCL)

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, matrix-multiplication

I'm attempting to optimize an OpenCL matrix multiplication program for an NVIDIA GeForce 9800 GT graphics card. I'm multiplying two 512x512 matrices, but I'm not sure what global and local work group sizes I should use. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Global size should ideally be as high as possible insofar as you do not need to interrupt the computation to add or modify inputs, if this is so then there are no diminishing returns to use as large a global size as you need. Though in practice, if you are using a GPU, most of them don't support task concurrency yet, so a GPU running your kernels will do only that. So if you were using it as a main graphics card, your screen will freeze. As for local work size, it depends on the kernel and the device, you can get OpenCL to try and optimize it (look up clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo)

Comment: Keep in mind that Nvidia GPUs group threads into groups of 32 threads (a warp), hence for coalesced memory access, you would want to have one dimension of the local work group size be a multiple of 32.

Answer (score 3):

As `512` is a **power of two**, you can try the following sizes:

```
size_t global_work_size[2] = {512, 512};
size_t  local_work_size[2] = {2^p, 2^n};
```

where :

- `(2^m + 2^n) % 32 = 0`: `32` must be a **divider** of your **number of threads**, as a wrap will contain `32` threads
- The **power of two** is need as the **local work size** must be a **divider** of the **global work size**.
- With a size of `512`, it will certainly not be a problem, but you have to take into account the `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` (given by `clGetDeviceInfo()`) parameter. For bigger matrices, you will have to use more than `2` dimensions.
- The number of dimensions is itself limited by `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS`...

Indeed the best choice is algorithm dependent, and depends on the kind of matrix multiplication you intend to perform.

Answer (score 3):

If you need peak performance, benchmark it with various local work group sizes and then use the best one. You might be surprised to find that the fastest one isn't always the one that matches the guidance given by the providers of the implementations!

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Dithermaster, and I want to add that the peak performance is highly platform-dependent, even the GPUs from the same vendor may have different optimal work group sizes if the GPUs are not the same model/generation.

To get the peak performance, you really need to experiment (pre-execution training) on the target platform and find the optimal configuration. Remember that not only the the work group size but also the work group shape could affect the performance significantly. That being said, you really need to try all the combinations as below. Suppose the max work group size for the kernel is 1024, which means for a 2-D work group, you can have the following combinations: (1, 1024), (2, 512), (4, 256), (8, 128), (16, 64), (32, 32), (64, 16), (128, 8), (256, 4), (512, 2), and (1024, 1).

Be careful that (1, 1024) and (1024, 1) could lead to totally different performance, due to the memory architecture, cache architecture and the way the wave is schedule and so on.

Yes, of course, you also need to consider wave/warp size as well as the coalesced memory access. Here, I am just talking about a general OpenCL workload, especially when the workload does not show any structural pattern, it would be good to experiment with as many as combinations to make sure you don't miss anything.

Comment: Exactly. In fact, often the fastest size is not the max size (based on register file size), so sizes like (8,16), (32,4) and everything else where WIDTH * HEIGHT <= MAX should be tested too.